# SQLAlchemy One-to-many, adding a record

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a query around adding a record with a one-to-many relationship.

First off, here are my models, I have a hierarchical one-to-many relationship with project/suite/case/step.

```
class Project(Base):
    """Project model for reportr"""
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80))

    #  Relationship definitions
    test_suites = relationship("TestSuite", backref="test_suite")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Project %r>' % self.name


class TestSuite(Base):
    """Test suite model for reportr"""
    __tablename__ = 'test_suite'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80))

    #  Relationship definitions
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("project.id"))
    test_cases = relationship("TestCase", backref="test_case")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<TestSuite %r>' % self.name


class TestCase(Base):
    """Test case model for reportr"""
    __tablename__ = 'test_case'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80))

    #  Relationship definitions
    test_suite_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("test_suite.id"))
    test_steps = relationship("TestStep", backref="test_step")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<TestCase %r>' % self.name


class TestStep(Base):
    """Test step model for reportr"""
    __tablename__ = 'test_step'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80))

    #  Relationship definitions
    test_case_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("test_case.id"))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<TestCase %r>' % self.name
```

I've got a function that accepts a dictionary, then stores the information in a database using SQLAlchemy.

```
def save(results):
    """Process the JSON file and save in the database"""
    test_json = json.load(results)
    session = init_session()

    for reportr in test_json['reportr']:
        for project in reportr['project']:
            prj = Project(name=project['name'])
            session.add(prj)
            print prj

            for suite in project['test_suite']:
                sui = TestSuite(name=suite['name'])
                sui.project_id = [prj]
                session.add(sui)
                print sui

                for case in suite['test_case']:
                    cas = TestCase(name=case['name'])
                    cas.test_suite_id = [sui]
                    session.add(cas)
                    print cas

                    for step in case['test_step']:
                        stp = TestStep(name=step['name'])
                        stp.test_case_id = [cas]
                        session.add(stp)
                        print stp

    session.commit()
```

Using TestSuite as an example...

At the moment I get an `InterfaceError` error due to me trying to save an object, not the ID into the `project_id` ForeignKey... this is fixed if I store `prj.id` into that field however `prj.id` is not populated until until I `add()` and `commit()` the changes.

From my experience I shouldn't be committing anything until all has processed but it seems like I can't set the relationship up without it?

My question is, am I approaching this in the wrong way? How can I add a `TestSuite` with a parent `Project` and some child `TestCases`?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `session.flush()` after `add` which should allow you to get back the db id:

```
session.add(sui)
session.flush()
print sui.id
```

Check the [transaction management docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html) for more details.

Comment: Ah thanks matino, I was just reading up on the use of `flush()` would this be safe to use after each insert and then I can commit at the end?